# Create polygons from polylines with polylines attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working in ArcMap 10.3.1 and I have a feature class with some 500,000 polylines, from what I need to generate polygons, that have to keep attributes from the polylines. I have tried the "Construct Polygons" tool in Edit mode, but it returns empty attributes table, and "Feature to Polygon", but it doesn't return attributes at all. I also tried the spatial join for the generated polygons with the lines feature class, but there are too many errors with attributes being assigned to incorrect features.

Is there any other method I can  use to achieve the goal of keeping attributes in the generated polygons?

Edit: added a couple of snapshots of line feature class fragment and, yes, they do overlap. [image: Close up view]

[image: Overview]

Comment: If you have a line that would be used for constructing two polygons (left and right), which one would get the attributes? Or should both get them?

Comment: Are these lines all overlapping, does a single line enclose isolated areas or are they contiguous as hinted by @user30184? I think you need to upload some images to explain your data, as it stands it's too vague on what you are asking?

Comment: Try feature to polygon GP tool. As long as the individual lines create a closed polygon it will do what you want. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/creating-polygons-from-lines.htm

Comment: I added a couple of snapshots of lines feature class to the question (the first one is close up view, the second overview, as @Hornbydd asked. Much of the lines are overlapping, some enclose isolated areas. The parameters the polygon feature class should get in best case scenario would the ones from lines, that make up most of the polygon border.

Comment: @Ben S Nadler the Feature To Polygon GP tool doesn't preserve attributes, so it can't be used.

Comment: Per the documentation, attributes are attached when supplied as label points. Convert your lines to points and use them as inputs for the line to poly tool. Preprocess your data by merging lines together to increase chances of success

Comment: In your image I assume you have colour coded the lines by ID (you don't really explain what we are seeing). So an "area" can be enclosed by 3 or more polylines. So what do you want your final polygon to be attributed with, if if it is composed of 4 polylines and how do you want to assign which polygon a line should attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I have solved this problem by using suggestion from @Ben S Nadler. First I generated polygons from lines, then I dissolved lines by their attributes, merging the lines with the same attribute, that make up same polygons. Then I coverted lines to points with GP tool Lines To Points and last I made a spatial join for generated polygons with the points created from lines.

In result I have got the attributes from lines feature class in my polygons feature class.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!